# Check If Any ListObjects Exist in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

If I am looping through my sheets and want to test if any ListObjects exist in the given sheet, how do I do this? I tried this:

```
Dim daysoftheweek As Worksheet
For Each daysoftheweek In Sheets
If Not daysoftheweek.ListObjects Is Nothing Then
'Do Something Here - Only If The Sheet Contains A List Object
End If
Next
```

But the IF conditional block still ran even when the sheet did not contain a ListObject.

Comment: `daysoftheweek.ListObjects.Count = 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Worksheet.ListObjects` is a collection so it isn't `Nothing`. Like Paul Bica commented, you want to count how many objects are in the collection. Try this:

```
Dim daysoftheweek As Worksheet

For Each daysoftheweek In Sheets
    If daysoftheweek.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
        'Do Something Here - Only If The Sheet Contains A List Object
    End If
Next
```